# can't convert byte array into original text

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on Bluetooth project where I am sending files from one android device to another. On server side I do get file and data. but the data written into file is in bytes format. I want to write original text in file. Methods like toString(), new String(byte[]), etc. are not working. Please can anyone help me with this. I have tried almost every code given in this site, as answer for such questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have tried `toString()` and `new String(byte[])` and you said its not working, so what do you mean by "Not working" , what's happening actually then?

Answer (score 0):

The `proper conversion` between `byte[]` and `String` is to explicitly state the encoding you want to use. If you start with a `byte[]` and it does not in fact contain text data, there is no proper conversion. `Strings` are for text, `byte[]` is for binary data, and the only really sensible thing to do is to avoid converting between them unless you absolutely have to.

The Best way to convert bytearray to String is

```
public void convertByteArrayToString(Charset encoding) {

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};

    String value = new String(byteArray, encoding);

    System.out.println(value);
}
```